# Variable turns to Null

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an app with two activities and one utility class to server both activities. The main activity passed info to the utility class and then the second activity will access that class and get that info. The problem is that someway along the way, the string I was passing becomes a null when the second activity is trying to get that string. Here is the methods I'm using for this (if more info is needed please let me know).

1. The method in the main activity to pass info to the utility class:

   ```
   public void setDateUT(int i){
       String s = Integer.toString(i);
       UT.getDate(s);
   }
   ```
2. The method in utility class to receive this info (and set it into the date variable):

   ```
   public class Utility {
       String date;
       public void getDate(String s){
      this.date = s;
   }
   ```
3. The method (and some extra info) in the 2nd activity to get this info back and set it in the TextView:

   ```
   String C;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.shifts);

       TextView setDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setdate);
       setDate();

       setDate.setText(C);
   }

   public void setDate(){
       C = UT2.setDate();
   }
   ```
4. The method to return date variable:

   ```
   public String setDate(){
       return date;
   }
   ```

Can you tell me whats wrong? why is my string not passing correctly and I'm getting a null instead?

Comment: Post the error log, and you have mixed up your getter and setter.

Comment: How are you passing an instance of the Utility class from one Activity class to another?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The debugger just shows me that the variable "date" value is "null". It doesn't accept the value of the string I was passing it for some reason I cant figure.

Comment: KAL - I'm writing "Utility UT2 = new Utility();" in the beginning of the activities class

Comment: Pompe, what do you mean I've mixed up my getter and setter?

Comment: @user811195 -- This is the reason why its null. You are creating a new object that has no idea about the first object created in your first activity.

Comment: Your code is unreadable to me, you should pay much more attention to java naming conventions. @user811195 is right, you are confusing getters and setters and it makes your code hard to follow, masquerading what seems to be quite big issues in understanding of method invocation, reuse of parameter and return values.

Comment: Can you offer me a better way to do it? I'm here to learn from you guys about the best practices. It would greatly help to show me examples of the correct way to do things

Comment: Kal, can you please tell me how to do it the right way?

Comment: @user811195 : your getter changes the value of the date, and your setter returns it. It should be the other way: a setter allows setting a new value in an object. A getter allows getting a value from an object.

Comment: JB Nizet: So basically I have the wrong method names for my methods? Or is it also a functional issue? And can someone please explain how do I use the same instance of my utility class from both of the activities?

Comment: Did some search, is a Singleton class is what I need?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, after doing some search and with your help (especially Kal) I realized what I need was my utility class to be a Singleton class. It works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your comments, after doing some search and with your help (especially Kal) I realized what I need was my utility class to be a Singleton class. It works great now!